# Using where_in in delete or select query codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use where_in in codeigniter delete function . I am imploding the array values which are integers received from the view. But since i need to pass them into where_in i implode it as :

```
implode(",",$delete_ids); //output: 12,13
```

But when i pass it to the query it displays as

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) WHERE `id` IN ('12,13');
```

I also tried using

```
implode("','",$delete_ids); // output:12','13
```

but when i pass it to the query function it shows :

```
SELECT * FROM (`table`) WHERE `id` IN ('12\',\'13')
```

not putting any extra parameters in it .

Please help me with a solution for this...Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **[codeigniter database documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)**, you can simply use `where_in()` function. You can use this:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $delete_ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass an array to where_in without implode(....),  your code will be like this:

```
$db->where_in('your_field', $delete_ids);
```